# How to use Laravel AssertJson for testing a structured response

Tags: laravel, laravel-testing

I have a signup API that returns a JSON response in this kind of format

```
{
    "meta": {
        //response metadata
    },
    "data": {
        //user object
    }
}
```

I want to test this response with `AssertableJson` but I'm only concerned about the user object.

**How do I use `AssertableJson` only for the data property of the response?**

I've tried something like this with no success

```
$response->data->assertJson(
            function(AssertableJson $json){
                $json->whereType('id', 'string')
                     ->where('email', 'email@gmail.com')
                     ->etc();
            }
        );
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use `has` to tell Laravel to look at the `data` key, and don't forget to use `etc()` [doc](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/http-tests#fluent-json-testing)

`etc()` allows an object to have additional keys not specified in the assert

```
$response->data->assertJson(fn (AssertableJson $json) =>
   $json->has('data', fn (AssertableJson $data) =>
      $data->whereType('id', 'string')
           ->where('email', 'email@gmail.com')
           ->etc()
   )->etc()
);
```